# PyPlot problems when building with Julia

Tags: julia, pycall, pycall.jl

I am having problems building PyCall in Julia (I am using a Mac). I have the message:

julia> Pkg.build("PyCall")
Building Conda ─→ `~/.julia/packages/Conda/3rPhK/deps/build.log`

Building PyCall → `~/.julia/packages/PyCall/BcTLp/deps/build.log`

```
┌ Error: Error building `PyCall`: 
│   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
│                                  Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
100 55.2M  100 55.2M    0     0  8088k      0  0:00:06  0:00:06 --:--:--  9.8M
│ ERROR: did not recognize option '1/.julia/conda/3', please try -h
│ ┌ Info: Using the Python distribution in the Conda package by default.
│ └ To use a different Python version, set ENV["PYTHON"]="pythoncommand" and re-run    Pkg.build("PyCall").
│ [ Info: Downloading miniconda installer ...
│ [ Info: Installing miniconda ...
│ ERROR: LoadError: failed process: Process(`'/Users/ymedinag 1/.julia/conda/3/installer.sh' -b -f -p '/Users/ymedinag 1/.julia/conda/3'`, ProcessExited(1)) [1]
│ Stacktrace:
│  [1] error(::String, ::Base.Process, ::String, ::Int64, ::String) at ./error.jl:42
│  [2] pipeline_error at ./process.jl:705 [inlined]
│  [3] #run#505(::Bool, ::Function, ::Cmd) at ./process.jl:663
│  [4] run at ./process.jl:661 [inlined]
│  [5] _install_conda(::String, ::Bool) at /Users/ymedinag 1/.julia/packages/Conda/3rPhK/src/Conda.jl:169
│  [6] _install_conda(::String) at /Users/ymedinag 1/.julia/packages/Conda/3rPhK/src/Conda.jl:155
│  [7] runconda(::Cmd, ::String) at /Users/ymedinag 1/.julia/packages/Conda/3rPhK/src/Conda.jl:112
│  [8] #add#1(::String, ::Function, ::String, ::String) at /Users/ymedinag 1/.julia/packages/Conda/3rPhK/src/Conda.jl:188
│  [9] add at /Users/ymedinag 1/.julia/packages/Conda/3rPhK/src/Conda.jl:187 [inlined] (repeats 2 times)
│  [10] top-level scope at /Users/ymedinag 1/.julia/packages/PyCall/BcTLp/deps/build.jl:84
│  [11] include at ./boot.jl:317 [inlined]
│  [12] include_relative(::Module, ::String) at ./loading.jl:1044
│  [13] include(::Module, ::String) at ./sysimg.jl:29
│  [14] include(::String) at ./client.jl:392
│  [15] top-level scope at none:0
│ in expression starting at /Users/ymedinag 1/.julia/packages/PyCall/BcTLp/deps/build.jl:43
└ @ Pkg.Operations /Users/julia/buildbot/worker/package_macos64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.0/Pkg/src/Operations.jl:1096
```

Would you have any idea to have PyCall properly installed ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem comes from the fact that there's a space in your username, or more specifically your user directory `/Users/ymedinag 1/`. Unfortunately, it seems to be a [known](https://superuser.com/questions/1495811/anaconda3-not-installing-due-to-space-in-path) [and](https://superuser.com/questions/1446749/where-do-i-install-anaconda-if-my-username-has-spaces-in-it-windows-10) [unresolved](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/3947) problem with Anaconda installers. Here, PyCall by default tries to use a miniconda Python, via Conda.jl, which in turn tries to install it via miniconda's `installer.sh` script. The problem comes from that script apparently being unable to deal with spaces in the installation directory.

Instead of using the default Julia-managed conda-Python (which is failing to install), you can instead install miniconda yourself to a directory without spaces, and then set `ENV["PYTHON"] = <your-miniconda-python-path>` before running `Pkg.build("PyCall")` again.

Comment: @ymg Glad to know! Please "accept" the answer by clicking the check/tick mark next to it, so that others will know the question has been solved.